# ORA-00907: missing right parenthesis while adding a new column

Tags: sql, oracle

```
create table student (
       name varchar2(20),
       s1 number(3),
       s2 number(3),
       s3 number(3)
);

insert into student values('ashok',50, 90, 70);

select name,s1,s2,s3, s1+s2+s3 "Total" 
from student;

select name,s1,s2,s3,if((s1+s2+s3)>(105)){'pass'}   "Total" 
from student 
group by name;
```

can anyone help how to print new column student is pass or fail seeing each subject.

Comment: oracle has no IF function. There's an IF statement in PL-SQL but no IF  function in Oracle SQL. Use case.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try this:

```
select distinct
    name,
    s1,
    s2,
    s3,
    case when (s1+s2+s3) > 105 then 'pass'
        else 'fail'
        end as "Total" 
from student;
```

Answer (score 1):

You can't use if like that.  The syntactical word you are looking for is CASE.

```
SELECT 
  name, s1,s2,s3,
  CASE
    WHEN (s1+s2+s3)>105 THEN 'Pass'
    ELSE 'Fail'
  END as 'Total'
FROM 
  student
```